# sql auto_increment/identity doesnt exist after executing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in eclipse - toad extension in sql...

```
CREATE table salesperson
(   
    Id auto_increment,
    Name varchar(40),
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

after executing this the console says

> SQL Error: ERROR: type "auto_incremet" does not exist

where is the problem??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Different systems, different syntaxes...

Comment: Based on screenshoot it is Postgresql

Comment: And where in the Postgres manual did you find the `auto_increment` syntax?

Comment: I thought it is sql...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify data type like `INTEGER`:

```
CREATE TABLE salesperson (
   Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Name VARCHAR(40),
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id) );
```

And with `IDENTITY` if using *SQL Server*:

```
 CREATE TABLE salesperson (
   Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   Name VARCHAR(40),
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id) );
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using Postgresql you can use `SERIAL`:

```
 CREATE TABLE salesperson (
   Id SERIAL,
   Name VARCHAR(40),
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id) );
```

or:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;

CREATE TABLE salesperson (
   Id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('my_seq'),
   Name VARCHAR(40),
   CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id) );
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a80ce/2/1)**

Comment: I have copied your code but still I am getting this message   http://s23.postimg.org/usnx8wy9n/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Try: `CREATE TABLE salesperson (
   Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Name VARCHAR(40) );`

Comment: @DahWaR Share image of entire query, tooltip hover code. It states cleary it is expecting `)`

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/7rbahckgf/Untitled.jpg
http://s9.postimg.org/qv4lxoxan/untitled_1.jpg

Comment: @DahWaR Try with identity instead

Comment: It has executed and after inserting it works proprely...thanks :)